# MATLAB Integration variable inside interpolation function

Tags: matlab, interpolation, symbolic-math, numerical-integration

I wish to perform an integration as indicated below.

I am facing an error because the I am using the integration variable 'u' inside interpolation function. (If I replace 'u' inside interpolation function by some constant, the integration runs fine.)

```
>>syms u
>>double(int(2*interp1(x,y,u),u,0,0.1))
   Error using interp1>Interp1D (line 330)
   Inputs must be floats, namely single or double.
    Error in interp1 (line 220)
    Vq = Interp1D(X,V,Xq,method);
```

Can you please provide some pointers to fix it.

P.S.: For clarification, y=f(x) [piecewise function] which is why I am interpolating to determine intermediate values.

Thanks a lot !!

Comment: Why are you using `syms u`? The input is numeric data, I would use numeric interpolation and integration as well.

Comment: @DanielR, Thanks for reply. 
if I omit `syms u` the integration fails:
     `>> double(int(2*interp1(x,y,u),u,0,0.1))`
     `Undefined function or variable 'u'.`
If I initialize u=0 then I get :
    `>> u=0;
    `>> double(int(2*interp1(x,y,u),u,0,0.1))`
     `Undefined function 'int' for input arguments of type 'double'.`

I am definitely not much familiar, so please forgive my ignorance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace `int` by a simpler integration routine, and forget about syms. Try the build-in `integrate`, or https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~dwharder/NumericalAnalysis/13Integration/romberg/matlab.html

Alternatively, you may find an alternative to `interp1`, and call `int` on each of its subintervals.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks folks for help,
I figured out that integral() fixes the issue instead of symbolic integ. Thanks a lot !!